# ffmpeg returns "method SETUP failed: 404 Not Found"

Tags: ffmpeg, rtsp

We're using ffmpeg (build ffmpeg-20190628-098ab93-win32-static) to take a snapshot from camera RTSP streams on a Win 10 system. On some cameras, we're getting this error:

```
[rtsp @ 06813ac0] method SETUP failed: 404 Not Found
rtsp://username:password@example.com: Server returned 404 Not Found
```

Here's an example command we use:

```
ffmpeg -y -i rtsp://username:password@example.com -vframes 1 -pix_fmt yuvj420p 
  -vf select='eq(pict_type\,I)' -q:v 1 _test.jpg
```

However, VLC can load the same stream (we can't use VLC, though) from the same machine. Additionally, we've opened the firewall to ffmpeg (it popped up the two firewall dialogs and we allowed it through).

We've found posts on the `DESCRIBE` error but nothing on `SETUP`. Any help is appreciated. Thank you.

**Update**: In VLC, that RTSP stream asks for credentials twice for some reason. Wondering if that's the cause.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The solution was [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55772260/177416) by @AmitSharma: We needed to wrap the RTSP address in double-quotes.

This didn't work:

```
ffmpeg -y -i rtsp://username:password@example.com -vframes 1 -pix_fmt yuvj420p 
  -vf select='eq(pict_type\,I)' -q:v 1 _test.jpg
```

We used this and it worked like a charm:

```
ffmpeg -y -i "rtsp://username:password@example.com" -vframes 1 -pix_fmt yuvj420p 
  -vf select='eq(pict_type\,I)' -q:v 1 _test.jpg
```