# How to solve "[rtsp @ 000002788daf24c0] method DESCRIBE failed: 454 Session Not Found" error in windows 10?

Tags: windows, rtsp, ip-camera, yolov5, yolov4

I am using YOLOv4 and YOLOv5 for object detection from IP Camera. When I used Hikvision camera, the program was successfully executed and I could get the expected result.
When I try to use a new camera from another company for object detection using YOLOv5, the following error is encountered.

```
[rtsp @ 00000207f6a7cb40] method DESCRIBE failed: 454 Session Not Found
```

I went through [this question in stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56808123/ffmpeg-returns-method-setup-failed-404-not-found) and tried using the double quoation mark before the camera ip address, but I failed.

I also found [this link](https://cxybb.com/article/qq_23093643/107729685), however this is for linux. I need for windows.

P.S.When I ping the camera ip address from command prompt, the ping is successful.
Also, the command for yolov5 used is:

```
python detect.py --source rtsp://username:password@xxx.xxx.x.xxx --weights bestweight.pt --conf 0.25
```

I do not have much knowledge regarding cameras. I would really appreciate if anyone could help me with this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tried and found the answer. I also need to enter trackID.
The follwoing command worked for me.

```
python detect.py --source rtsp://username:password@xxx.xxx.x.xxx/trackID=1 --weights bestweight.pt --conf 0.25
```

Comment: What is track id? How to find that? How can I mention track id for multiple cameras

Comment: @iamharry I do not much about these all. The thing I know is: You can create multiple profiles in some (or all, I am not sure) IP cameras. The trackID=1 refers to profile 1.